# Powershell script which will search folders with regex and which will delete files older than XX

Tags: powershell

I need a powershell script ;

- it must search some subfolders which folders names are starting with character between 1 and 6 (like 1xxxx or 2xxx)
- and using the name of these folders as variable it must look under each folder for the *.XML files which are older than 30 min
- and if it finds them it must delete it.
- there may be more than one folder at same time, which are providing the same conditions so IMO using an array is a good choice. But I'm always open to other ideas.

Anybody can help me please ?

Basically I was using this before the need changes but now it doesnt help me.

```
powershell -nologo -command Get-ChildItem -Path C:\geniusopen\inbox\000\ready\processed | Where CreationTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | remove-item
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following and just remove `-WhatIf` if you are satisfied with the results:

```
$Time = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\MostCommonLeaf' -Recurse -File -Filter '*.xml' |
    Where {$_.CreationTime -lt $Time -and (Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) -match '^[1-6]' -and $_.Extension -eq '.xml'} |
        Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

`MostCommonLeaf` would be the lowest level folder that could start as your root search node. We essentially don't want to traverse directories for nothing.

You could potentially make the script above better if you know more about your directory structure. For example, if it is predictable within the path where the `1xxx` folders will be, you can construct the `-Path` parameter to use the `[1-6]` range wildcard. `-Filter '*.xml'` could also return `.xmls` files for example, so that's why there is additional extension condition in the `Where`.

Using `-Recurse` and `-Include` together generally results in much slower queries. So even if tempted, I would avoid a solution that uses those together.

If there are millions of files/directories, a different command construction could be better. Running `Split-Path` millions of times could be less efficient than just matching on the directory name, e.g. `where {$_.DirectoryName -match '\\[1-6][^\\]*$'}`.

Comment: Thank you. I will test immediately and respond you. thanks again for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
$path = "C:\Users\you\xxx"
$Extension = "*.xml"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $Extension -Force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | Remove-Item
```

I haven't tested it though.

Keep in mind whether you need: $*.CreationTime or $*.LastWriteTime

Comment: Miyuki thank you but it doesnt provides the conditions that I wrote below. Please look at the conditions if you still want to help.

Comment: Do you mean the length is 1 to 6 or the name starts with a number that could be from 1 to 6?

Comment: first condition ; the folder name must start with [1-6] and of course it may exist more than one folder at same time. so I guess using an array is a good choice.